# Como incluir linhas em um data.frame?

Tags: r, data.frame

Considere o seguinte `data.frame`:

```
df <- data.frame(x=c("a","b"), y=c(1,2))
```

Como incluir uma nova linha com x="c" e y=3 no `data.frame`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A função `rbind` faz uma cópia do `data.frame`para depois adicionar a linha, o que a torna ineficiente.

Uma alternativa é usar a função `rbind_list` do pacote `dplyr`:

```
linha <- data.frame(x="c", y=3)
library(dplyr)
df <- rbind_list(df, linha)
```

Neste caso, como estamos incluindo um novo nível do fator x, ela nos dá um aviso que está convertendo a variável para tipo `character`.

O benchmark está abaixo:

```
library(microbenchmark)
time <- microbenchmark(
  rbind_list(df, linha),
  rbind(df, linha)
  )
time
## Unit: microseconds
##                   expr     min      lq   median       uq     max neval
##  rbind_list(df, linha)  85.342  90.478  95.2195 100.9485 234.295   100
##       rbind(df, linha) 258.396 269.855 279.1390 294.7460 528.250   100
```

Answer (score 5):

Uma forma de fazer isso é criar um novo `data.frame` com a linha que se deseja incluir e utilizar a função `rbind`:

```
linha <- data.frame(x="c", y=3)
df <- rbind(df, linha)
df
  x y
1 a 1
2 b 2
3 c 3
```

Answer (score 2):

Uma outra possibilidade é usando a função `add_row()` do `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)

add_row(df, x="c", y=3)

  x y
1 a 1
2 b 2
3 c 3
```